# FluentNHibernate Many-To-Many Conditional Count on Child

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Consider the following entities:

```
Package        Manifest       Content
----------     ----------     ----------     
Id             PackageId      Id
Name           ContentId      Name
                              Status
```

The relationship is many-to-many where a package can have multiple contents and contents can belong to multiple packages.

What I'd like to do is, for a given `Package.Id`, get the count of all `Content` which have a specific `Status`.

My mapping works fine, but I have not been able to figure out how to achieve a conditional count of the `Content` without loading the `Content`.  One option is to use an `ApplyChildFilter` in the mapping and use with `ExtraLazyLoad`, but this means I'd have to create a dedicated property just for this.

Is there a way to achieve this without falling back on `CreateSQLQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query work for you?

```
  session
    .QueryOver<Package>()
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Manifest)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Content)
    .Where(x => x.Status == someStatus)
    .Select(Projections.RowCount())
    .FutureValue<int>()
    .Value
```

Comment: the issue is that the Manifest is not explicitly mapped since it's implicitly mapped via `HasManyToMany.Table("Manifest").ParentKeyColumn("PackageId").ChildKeyColumn("ContentId")`.  I think your proposal would work if I added an explicit mapping and property for the Manifest, but I was hoping for some way to avoid that (right now just using SQL to basically do this JOIN).